# Error sending request to OpenRouteService API from a set of client addresses to a foodbank site

Tags: python, routing, api, spyder

I am sending a request to OpenRouteService API from a set of client addresses to a foodbank site:

I am passing coordinates in the form ((x1,x2),(y1,y2)) where x coordinates are from a large csv file, and the y coordinate is the extra appended coordinate.

I sent a successful request (for a single coordinate pair) to openrouteservice in the form

cords = ((8.34234,48.23424),(8.34423,48.26424))

I am now trying to send a request for a large batch of coordinate pairs.

```
import csv
import openrouteservice
client = openrouteservice.Client(key='myAPIkey')

with open ('ClientCoordinates.csv' , 'r') as csv_coords:
   csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_coords) 
   EXTRA_COORD = [53.464774, 2.23179]
   csv_coords = []
   for line in csv_reader:
       csv_coords.append([line, EXTRA_COORD])

coords = (csv_coords)
routes = client.directions(coords)

print(routes)
```

This returns ApiError:

> 400 ({'error': {'code': 2002, 'message': "Parameter 'coordinates' has
>   incorrect value or format."}, 'info': {'engine': {'version': '5.0.1',
>   'build_date': '2019-05-29T14:58:37Z'}, 'timestamp': 1567170534336}})

Perhaps my use of brackets is incorrect, as OpenRouteService requires coordinate inputs in ().

Comment: Please , format your code properly. Python is an indented language. Without proper indentation the code you provided should give you an Indent Error.

Comment: What is the exact format the API needs, and what are you passing as coords? Please, print it and include these info in your question by editing it.

Comment: I highly recommend removing your API key and locking it down if at all possible. Even if this is a free API, someone else using your key could limit the amount of requests you can make, and it's good practice for other APIs.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, I have corrected the indentation and added coordinate info. I have also hidden my API key.

Comment: (Keep in mind that people can look back at the edits, so if there's a way to lock the API key down, that's still recommended.)

Comment: How does `'ClientCoordinates.csv'` file look like (two or three rows are sufficient)?

Comment: It looks like you are currently sending too many coordinates at once. If you adjust your indentation for the last two lines, you should get each set of directions one at a time.

Comment: @smiller I son't know much about OpenRouteService, but from [the examples](https://github.com/GIScience/openrouteservice-py#usage) it seems sending more coordinates at a time is feasible.

Comment: Thanks for linking that, their main website sent me to a login screen when I looked for developer docs. It looks like the only place where multiple coordinates are listed are in the Traveling Salesman example (multiple stops along the way), so I still think it'll be best to send them one at a time as it looks like they are looking for directions between a single location and the client coordinates.

Comment: Thanks for all your helpful comments!!  My csv file coordinates look like this when printed out   [[['53.457321', '-2.262773'], [53.464774, 2.23179]], [['53.467355', '-2.240089'], [53.464774, 2.23179]], [['53.473451', '-2.177722'],  So I think perhaps the API is not accepting this format.

Comment: Indeed, you have incorrect parenthesis colsing, and some of your numbers are of string formats (like '53.467355'). You should cast the numbers coming from the csv as strings to floating numbers with `float()`. I have updated my answer to reflect that (and also to make a single request per coordinate pair as per @smiller comments).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess from [this link](https://github.com/GIScience/openrouteservice-py#usage) that `OpenRouteService` requires a tuples of coordinates within a parent tuple like:

```
coords = ((8.34234,48.23424),(8.34423,48.26424))
```

You have to provide the API the exact format it needs otherwise it will complain.

Also, you are overwriting the `csv_coords` variable name, by defining it twice

I don't know how your `'ClientCoordinates.csv'` looks like, but, as long as it is something like:

```
1,2
3,4
```

you can do:

```
import csv
import openrouteservice
client = openrouteservice.Client(key='YOUR_SECRET_KEY_HERE') # NEVER SHOW YOUR KEY IN PUBLIC WEBSITE!

with open ('ClientCoordinates.csv' , 'r') as csv_coords:
   csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_coords)
   EXTRA_COORD = (53.464774, 2.23179) # CHANGE THIS to a tuple
   new_csv_coords = []
   for line in csv_reader:
       new_csv_coords.append(((float(line[0]), float(line[1])), EXTRA_COORD))

        coords = (new_csv_coords)
        print(coords[0])
        routes = client.directions(coords[0])

        print(routes)
```

Comment: Unless the format changed considerably since [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flJx1rFvcc) was produced, coordinates are OK in lists instead of tuples. Either way, I don't see any option for multiple sets of coordinates to be passed at once except in route optimization (multiple stops).

Comment: You're probably right, although as you also found out, it is hard to tell without any accessible API docs (at least, without the need to create an account).

Comment: Yes, it looks like I need to pass pairs of coordinates through one at a time, rather than all at once.

Comment: I tried this method and got this error - ApiError: 404 ({'error': {'code': 2010, 'message': 'Cannot find point 0: -2.262773,53.457321; Cannot find point 1: 2.23179,53.464774'}, 'info': {'engine': {'version': '5.0.1', 'build_date': '2019-05-29T14:22:56Z'}, 'timestamp': 1567179201693}})

Comment: Did other coordinates worked or everything is giving you this issue? Seems the format is fine now, but that ORS cannot find the points. Maybe these links can help you finding out a solution:https://ask.openrouteservice.org/t/cannot-find-point-1-46-918-10-09555/783/3, https://ask.openrouteservice.org/t/cannot-find-point-with-negatives-cords/521

Comment: I solved the issue in the csv file, thanks. I am now getting - Request parameters exceed the server configuration limits. The approximated route distance must not be greater than 6000000.0 meters - the API key allows 2000 direction requests and I am only trying 100.

Comment: Glad you solved it. That is probably an issue that should be asked as a separate question or even better on ask.openrouteservice.org. If my answer did solve your problem, feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The API's website has its documentation behind a login, so I could not get a written version of this, but based on the slide at 14:13 of this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=flJx1rFvccE the directions API needs two pairs of coordinates -- I assume the from and two coordinates. From the examples linked by @umbe1987 in the comments above, it's possible to send more than 2 coordinates, but those appear only in the section for Traveling Salesman (optimizing a route of multiple stops.)

Your code is passing an entire list of coordinates at once.

Suggestion: Adjust indentation and add another list to capture the routes.

```
import csv
import openrouteservice
client = openrouteservice.Client(key='myAPIkey')

with open ('ClientCoordinates.csv' , 'r') as csv_coords:
   csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_coords) 
   EXTRA_COORD = [53.464774, 2.23179]
   csv_coords = []
   routelist = []
   for line in csv_reader:
       csv_coords.append([line, EXTRA_COORD])

        coords = (csv_coords)
        routes = client.directions(coords)
        print(routes)
        routelist.append(routes)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!